# Eagle 'optional' solder pads

Tags: soldering, eaglecad, pad

I'm currently designing a PCB with inter-board interconnects - I figure that right-angle 0.1" headers will be sufficient. I'll be "mass producing" the boards (only a couple of dozen...) so I need them all to be the same.

But it turns out that some of the pins will be optional; that is, configurable at construction time. So I want to design in some PCB pads that can be quickly soldered across to implement - or not - the required functionality. I've seen pads that look like `-CD-` or `-Pd-` (imagine the 'holes' in those letters filled with copper, just waiting for a solder bridge...)

I'm using Eagle (7.6.0) and thought there'd be a "component" that could be added to the schematic, and therefore the PCB, but I can't find anything. Am I not looking correctly? (I don't know the search term.) Or do I have to learn the whole "solder pad" system of Eagle too?

Comment: The device is called SJ in *jumper* library. Finally, you can make your own device. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm quite sure you are looking for solder jumpers. The build-in library "jumper" has two types SJ and SJ2 with two or three terminals:

[image]

And just what it looks like on the PCB, with a 1206 resistor for size comparison:

[image]

Comment: See? "Jumper" is the magic search term. Thank you!

Comment: Ooohhh... I was hoping for the `-CD-` look! But thanks anyway